# Makefile putting child on chain

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm working with a makefile and I'm currently running in debug mode.  I noticed the "putting child 0x5435etc PID 2344 on the chain"  Is this makefiles way of remembering what files are generated?

I ask because I'm using a tool that generates a bunch of different file types of of a target like below.

```
    %.v: $.rdl
       (Generates .html, .v, .vh, .xml, .spirit.xml, etc into current directory)
```

The tool generates all the files as expected and desired.

Then the makefile runs a target

```
    vpath %.spirit.xml ${list_of_directories}
    %.ralf: %.spirit.xml
       (Generates a .ralf and .spirit.ralf)
```

The very first time I run "$ make " in a clean directory it generates the list of .v files on the first target, but then fails on the first .ralf.  If I run "$ make " again it correctly builds all of the .ralf files.  Any possible easy answers?  I noticed that when it puts children into the chain for the %.v target it only ever puts the .v files!  I was thinking it might not know the others exist!

Comment: Why did I get marked down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you will need to tell Make that that command produces multiple outputs.

This should work:

```
%.html %.v %.vh %.xml %.spirit.xml: %.rdl
        # command
```

See [Pattern examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Examples) in the manual.

Comment: I see!  That makes sense!  Does this tell make that there is only one scenario where it is guaranteed to make all of those files at once?

Comment: What do I do if I generate a few files with different names than the target?

Comment: @MattCarlis Yes, that tells make that `command` produces all those files at once. The last example in the [Pattern Rule Examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Examples) section of the manual explains it in more detail.